# Selectize.js remote data source items with same valueField but different labelField do not display correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

There is a known [issue](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/issues/129) with [selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) where if an item has the same valueField it will only display the first value. This also applies to a remote data source.

For example:

```
- value: 1, label: Apple
- value: 1, label: Steve
- value: 2, label: Google
- value: 2, label: Eric
```

If I do a search for Google it gives me a result as expected. But if I now do a search for Eric; that will not show up since the value of 2 has already been shown. If I refresh the page and then search for Eric it works; but now I cannot search for google

Here is my code:

```
$('#supplier').selectize({
            valueField: 'value',
            labelField: 'label',
            searchField: 'label',
            options: [],
            create: false,
            render: {
                option: function(item, escape) {
                    return '<div class="customer-badge suggestions">' +
                                '<div class="avatar">' +
                                    '<img src="' + escape(item.avatar) + '" alt="">' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<div class="details">' +
                                    '<a href="#" class="name">' +
                                        escape(item.label) +
                                    '</a>' +
                                    '<span class="email">' +
                                        escape(item.email) + 
                                    '</span>' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</div>';
                }
            },

            load: function(query, callback) {
                if (!query.length) return callback();
                $.ajax({
                    url:'<?php echo site_url("receivings/supplier_search");?>'+'?term='+encodeURIComponent(query),
                    type: 'GET',
                    error: function() {
                        callback();
                    },
                    success: function(res) {
                        res = $.parseJSON(res);
                        callback(res);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

I have tried the following:

1. Replaced entire code with https://github.com/BlueBayTravel/selectize.js/tree/allow-duplicates and set option `duplicate: true` and `mode: "multi"`. This did NOT change behavior. I think they might have done their solution for just local data sources.
2. Attempted to figure out the discussion on the [issue page](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/issues/129); but it was for an older version; I tried my best but could NOT get it to work.

At this point I will take any dirty patch as this is a major issue and I am not sure why this has NOT been addressed in any way

Comment: Perhaps you can handle it outside of this code? Append a random character to the value then strip it when parsing? I've been using selectize a TON, have heavily customized it, and have never needed duplicate values. You talk about it like it's the end of the world "a major issue" but I believe it's only a major issue for the minority. If no one else addresses this I'll take a look at it on Monday and see if I can get you something.

Comment: @basher no need to look at it. We found another problem where if the search doesn't contain a value in the label it doesn't show in the result even though it is returned in the response. We have decided to use a different plugin. These issues make it not possible to use. The reason we need duplicate values is you can search by name, company, email and it will all relate back to the same value.